# Why doesn't a SPARQL POST query to the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint work with the Python urllib3 library when the corresponding requests query does?

Tags: post, python-requests, sparql, urllib3, wikidata-query-service

I want to make the SPARQL query to the Wikidata Query Service using query via URL-encoded POST (method 2) rather than GET (method 1) since GET queries have a limited length and some queries may be long if a lot of VALUES data are sent. Based on my past experience using query via POST directly (method 3), it has problems with character encoding at the Wikidata Query Service. The three methods for performing SPARQL queries via HTTP are described in the W3C SPARQL 1.1 specification.

I want to use the Python `urllib3` library rather than `requests`, since this code will be part of an AWS Lambda and `requests` is no longer a supported library in the `boto3` SDK. I could import `requests` as a layer, but I would prefer to keep things simple by just using `urllib3`.

I have been making URL-encoded POST HTTP queries using the `requests` library for a long time with no problems. However, when I use the analogous code for the `urllib3` library, I get an error. I am mystified by this behavior, particularly since the `requests` library is just a wrapper over `urllib3`. There must be something that `requests` is adding to the HTTP request that `urllib3` isn't. I've read the docs and looked at examples for making POST requests with `urllib3` and can't see anything I'm missing. I tried URL encoding the query (commented out in the code below), but that didn't make any difference.

I queried the Wikidata Query Service SPARQL endpoint using the following Python code and the requests library:

```
import requests

query_string = 'SELECT ?item WHERE {?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.}LIMIT 10'

requestheader = {
    'User-Agent': 'TestAgent/0.1 (mailto:email@domain.com)', 
    'Accept': 'application/sparql-results+json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    
response = requests.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', data={'query' : query_string}, headers=requestheader)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.headers)
print(response.text)
```

As expected, I received the following response from the API:

```
200
{'server': 'nginx/1.18.0', 'date': 'Thu, 22 Feb 2024 21:18:02 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/sparql-results+json;charset=utf-8', 'x-first-solution-millis': '1', 'x-served-by': 'wdqs1015', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'cache-control': 'public, max-age=300', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'vary': 'Accept, Accept-Encoding', 'age': '0', 'x-cache': 'cp1106 miss, cp1106 pass', 'x-cache-status': 'pass', 'server-timing': 'cache;desc="pass", host;desc="cp1106"', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=106384710; includeSubDomains; preload', 'report-to': '{ "group": "wm_nel", "max_age": 604800, "endpoints": [{ "url": "https://intake-logging.wikimedia.org/v1/events?stream=w3c.reportingapi.network_error&schema_uri=/w3c/reportingapi/network_error/1.0.0" }] }', 'nel': '{ "report_to": "wm_nel", "max_age": 604800, "failure_fraction": 0.05, "success_fraction": 0.0}', 'x-client-ip': '129.59.122.76', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'content-length': '217'}
{
  "head" : {
    "vars" : [ "item" ]
  },
  "results" : {
    "bindings" : [ {
      "item" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q378619"
      }
    }, {
      "item" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q498787"
      }
    }, {
      "item" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q677525"
      }
    }, {
      "item" : {
        "type" : "uri",
...
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

However, when I make the analogous request using the urllib3 library I get an error. Code:

```
import urllib3
#import urllib.parse

query_string = 'SELECT ?item WHERE {?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.}LIMIT 10'
# Try url encoding the query string. I think this isn't necessary because I think urllib3 already does this.
#query_string = urllib.parse.quote(query_string)
#print(query_string)

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

requestheader = {
'User-Agent': 'TestAgent/0.1 (mailto:email@domain.com)', 
'Accept': 'application/sparql-results+json',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = http.request('POST', 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', fields={'query' : query_string}, headers=requestheader)
print(response.status)
print(response.headers)
print(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Response:

```
405
HTTPHeaderDict({'server': 'nginx/1.18.0', 'date': 'Mon, 26 Feb 2024 13:17:45 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1', 'x-served-by': 'wdqs1018', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'age': '0', 'x-cache': 'cp1108 miss, cp1108 pass', 'x-cache-status': 'pass', 'server-timing': 'cache;desc="pass", host;desc="cp1108"', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=106384710; includeSubDomains; preload', 'report-to': '{ "group": "wm_nel", "max_age": 604800, "endpoints": [{ "url": "https://intake-logging.wikimedia.org/v1/events?stream=w3c.reportingapi.network_error&schema_uri=/w3c/reportingapi/network_error/1.0.0" }] }', 'nel': '{ "report_to": "wm_nel", "max_age": 604800, "failure_fraction": 0.05, "success_fraction": 0.0}', 'x-client-ip': '166.194.158.40', 'content-length': '13'})
Not writable.
```

I cannot see any problems with the `urllib3` request. The Wikdiata Query Service is a public API and no authentication is required.

Comment: I tried to post the link to the W3C SPARQL 1.1 specification, but that seemed to be causing the post to be flagged as spam. The URL is: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#query-operation

Comment: for `POST` request, you could at least try to workaround and encode the args manually: `from urllib.parse import urlencode` and `encoded_args = urlencode({"query": query_string})` `req_obj = http.request("POST", "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?" + encoded_args)` `print(req_obj.data)` - maybe that's already sufficient

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. the method `request` does not form-urlencode the data by default. You have to append `encode_multipart = False` as argument: `response = http.request('POST', 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', fields={'query' : query_string}, headers=requestheader, encode_multipart = False)`